# Why isn't eclipse deploying my Dynamic Web Project correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, deployment

Here's the problem: I have a java "dynamic web project" under source control and checked out in my eclipse workspace. Before, I was able to run a servlet on a local Tomcat server from within eclipse. However, I pulled some changes which got rid of some files and added some new ones.

Now Eclipse looks like it's not deploying the web app to the tomcat directory. I looked at the folder where Eclipse previously deployed it (under .metadata) but nothing gets copied there anymore. I figure there's something wrong with my build configuration, what are some possible causes or steps to go through to find out the problem?

I am however able to deploy/run the web app with an Ant script that I have written, and it works correctly when executed.

Comment: I know it sounds tedious, but delete and recreate web server configuration.  In my experience it helps 90% of the time.

Comment: I'd second Alexander's suggestion. Also, if everything else fails, recreate workspace and pull all projects from source control again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without more information. I'd start by checking any errors in console when starting Tomcat. How does the problem manifest, what got you looking if the files did get copied? If I'm unable to find a specific problem, there's some random stuff / voodoo rituals to try (sometimes Eclipse just needs a bit of attention):

- Check Window / Preferences and then Java / Installed JREs and Server / Runtime environments. Click on Edit, see if Eclipse reports any errors.
- Check your project's build path - right click on Project / Build path / Configure build path. Go through all tabs; anything red needs fixing.
- Try opening Window / Show view and look at both Error log (which contains Eclipse errors) and Problems (any compiler warnings/problems).
- Sometimes Project / Clean helps.
- Try right clicking on your server in Servers view and choosing Clean.
- Try starting eclipse with -clean option.