# How to reload java class automatically in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in eclipse which contains both a jsp file and a java class. But when I make a change in my java class, eclipse does not understand the changes in the class until I close eclipse and open it again. It is very annoying that I have to close eclipse and open it after even just adding a print statement. How can I fix this?

example, lets say i have this method :

```
public String m1(){
     return "Johnny";
}
```

and this statement in jsp file:

```
<%= a.m1() &>
```

(I am passing jsp:useBean  part of jsp our class name is a )

this prints "Johnny".Then i make change on method like this:

```
public String m1(){
  return "Liz";
}
```

after this, i build my project.But it still prints Johnny rather than Liz.When i close eclipse and reopen it this time it prints Liz.

Comment: In the menu, select: Project > Build automatically

Comment: Yeah I did this but even it builds there is no change  until I close eclipse

Comment: You are invoking your web server incorrectly on your code. Add details on how you currently work.

Comment: i hope i make it clear this time

Comment: @user3783144 How are you *invoking* the JSP?

Comment: like this : <%@ page import="java.io.* ,java.util.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="a" class="harun.Todalar"scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="a" />

Comment: Sorry, how are you causing the JSP page to be evaluated. i.e. How are you getting it to display "Johnny" instead of the source `<% a.m1() &>`? A webserver? An eclipse plugin / view ?

Comment: ok it is same thing but lets say im writing this : <% out.println(a.m1())%> btw im working on dynamic web project

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179621/eclipse-dynamic-web-project-not-picking-up-changes-in-jsp-or or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952347/why-isnt-eclipse-deploying-my-dynamic-web-project-correctly

Answer (score 2):

To get eclipse to recompile your code:

```
Project -> Build All
```

or just hit **Ctrl+B**

To have that happen whenever you make a change (and save it):

```
Project -> Build Automatically
```

---

To have eclipse notice when you make a change to a file *even from outside eclipse*:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or polling
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Eclipse. Try downloading the [latest](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar) Eclipse version.
Before that try these things:

- Clean Project
- Delete meta data of workspace, create new work space and import project again.